# After Jessie upgrade: "A start job is running for dev-mmcpblk01p1.device"

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-jessie

My Pi2 is not booting anymore after upgrade to Jessie (using the standard apt-get route).

During boot I get a bunch of messages, the first one is the "A start job is running for dev-mmcpblk01p1.device", which takes about 90 seconds. Then I get messages like

```
[FAILED] Failed to start Trigger Flushing of Journal to Persistent Storage
[FAILED] Failed to start Update UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for Update UTMP about System Runlevel Change
```

How can I repair this? I have never worked with systemd before.

Comment: Do you have another Linux box?  I'd put that SD card in another box and do a file system check if you can.

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with the filesystem... I think this is more some problem with the new systemd.

Comment: otherwise this is another possible solution: had the same problem and solved it thanks to your suggestion. it seems there is a problem with the new systemd in jessie and handling raid / tmpfs. cause i wanted to use tmpfs, i switched back to sysvinit like described here: http://sohcahtoa.org.uk/osd.html - so thats a second way. if sb. finds out what exactly the problem is and how to solve with systemd, i would be great, if you could post it here,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the problem was caused by me. I was using tmpfs for several directories under /var, to prevend Plex Media Server from spamming my SD-card full of useless logs.

After commenting out the tmpfs sections in my /etc/fstab, everything was fine again.

Comment: As a note: I still wonder why systemd doesn't play well with tmpfs...? Will have to investigate further.

Comment: systemd plays okay with my RAM disc.

Comment: Yeah, I have to figure out some other time why this broke everything. Will report back with a solution when I have one.